# Adding 'rayOrigin: mouse' to Aframe cursor component throwing error

Tags: aframe

I am trying to include a mouse click functionality to VR scene apart from focus cursor.  I am using it as below -

```
 <a-entity camera look-controls mouse-cursor>
    <a-entity position="0 0 -3" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusOuter: 0.20;radiusInner: 0.10;" material="color: #990000; shader: flat" cursor=" fuse: true; rayOrigin: mouse">

    </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

Below is the error while using this code. Please note that i am using Afrmae with Angular2

```
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
at Mesh.raycast (aframe-master.js:21938)
at intersectObject (aframe-master.js:45999)
at Raycaster.intersectObjects (aframe-master.js:46072)
at NewComponent.module.exports.Component.registerComponent.tick (aframe-master.js:69697)
at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:76597)
at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:76645)
at bound (aframe-master.js:79931)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
```

Comment: Here is the glitch showing the problem.          
                                                                        https://glitch.com/edit/#!/useful-servant?path=index.html:65:15

Answer (score 1):

If you want your mouse to act like a `<a-cursor>` You need to move the `cursor` bit to the `<a-scene>` :

```
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin:mouse">
```

Comment: Tried this solution but still getting the same error. One more point that i want to highlight is that the error that i am getting is inconsistent. Some time it works fine  but most of the time getting error.